# Probability of an unbalanced coin

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

This was an optional practice problem in statistics: An unbalanced coin has a 0.3 probability of being heads. The coin is tossed 20 times, let Y be the number of heads recorded.

a) Find the distribution of Y.

b) Find E(Y) and V(Y).

c) Find probability that Y falls within 2 standard deviations of the mean.

What I've got is as follows:
a) I'm guessing it's binomial distribution, since we're looking for the number of successes.

b) (since it's binomial): $E(Y)=np=0.3*20 = 6$ and $V(Y)=np(1-p)=4.2$

c) What do I compare to 2 standard deviations, or [0,14.4]? I'm guessing I take $p*14.4$, which is 4.32, and take $4.32/6$, so the answer is that 2 standard deviations is within 72% of the mean.

I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I hate biased coin problems. See "You Can Load a Die, But You Can’t Bias
a Coin". http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/diceRev2.pdf So only the throw can be biased, not the coin itself.

Comment: That is an interesting essay, but i don't think that helps me solve this problem :D I guess I should say that there's a computer program that spits out "Head" 30% of the time and "Tails" 70% of the time. Thanks.

Comment: I understand... Just thought you might be a smart ass and bring that point up with the teacher.

Comment: The "problem" here is that (on average) the binomial distribution gives a "histogram" for an integer  number of tosses. You can do 1/2 a toss. But the V(Y) is a real number but not an integer. Agreed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard deviation is the square root of the variance $\sigma \approx 2.04$

you are looking for the probability that $6- 2\sigma < Y < 6+2\sigma$

since Y has to be an integer you are interested in values between 2 and 10.

So your answer will be ...

$$ P = \sum_{k=2}^{10}\binom {20} k (0.3)^k(0.7)^{20-k} $$